# In a tree, how do I find paths to tree nodes that have children with leaves?

Tags: clojure

Basically, I am trying to implement this algorithm, though maybe there's a better way to go about it.

- starting at the root
- check each child of current node for children with leafs (child of child)
- if any child-of-child nodes of the current node have leafs, record path to current node (not to child) and **do not continue down that path any farther.**
- else continue DFS

non-functional pseudo code:

```
def find_paths(node):
    for child in node.children:
       if child.children.len() == 0
          child_with_leaf = true
    if child_with_leaf
       record path to node
    else
       for child in node.children
           find_paths(child)
```

For example:

```
:root
  |- :a
  |   +- :x
  |       |- :y
  |       |   +- :t
  |       |       +- :l2
  |       +- :z
  |          +- :l3
  +- :b
      +- :c
          |- :d
          |   +- :l4
          +- :e
              +- :l5
```

The result would be:

```
[[:root :a]
 [:root :b :c]]
```

Here is my crack at it in clojure:

```
(defn atleast-one?
  [pred coll]
  (not (nil? (some pred coll))))

; updated with erdos's answer
(defn children-have-leaves?
  [loc]
  (some->> loc
           (iterate z/children)
           (take-while z/branch?)
           (atleast-one? (comp not empty? z/children))))

(defn find-paths
  [tree]
  (loop [loc (z/vector-zip tree)
         ans nil]
    (if (z/end? loc)
      ans
      (recur (z/next loc)
             (cond->> ans
                      (children-have-leaves? loc)
                      (cons (->> loc z/down z/path (map z/node)))))))
  )

(def test-data2
  [:root [:a [:x [:y [:t [:l2]]] [:z [:l3]]]] [:b [:c [:d [:l4]] [:e [:l5]]]]]
  )
```

Update:   fixed the crash with erdos' answer below, but I think there's still a problem with my code since this prints every path and not the desired ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have referenced my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56042982/6013799) related to zipper.  But please note that my previous answer uses `vector-zip` as is and hence you have to navigate it like a `vector-zip` - which you may have to wrap your head around how the two cursors work.  To simplify the navigation, I suggest you create your own zipper for your tree structure.  I.e.

```clj
(defn my-zipper [root]
  (z/zipper ;; branch?
            (fn [x]
              (when (vector? x)
                (let [[n & xs] x] (and n (-> xs count zero? not)))))
            ;; children
            (fn [[n & xs]] xs)
            ;; make-node
            (fn [[n & _] xs] [n xs])
            root))
```

then the solution will be similar to my other answer:

```clj
(def test-data2
  [:root 
   [:a 
    [:x 
     [:y 
      [:t [:l2]]] 
     [:z [:l3]]]] 
   [:b 
    [:c 
     [:d [:l4]] 
     [:e [:l5]]]]])

(->> test-data2
     my-zipper
     (iterate z/next)
     (take-while (complement z/end?))
     (filter (comp children-with-leaves? z/node))
     (map #(->> % z/path (map z/node)))
     set)
;; => #{(:root :a :x) (:root :a :x :y) (:root :b :c)}
```

where the main logic is simplified to:

```clj
(defn children-with-leaves? [[_ & children]]
  (some (fn [[c & xs]] (nil? xs)) children))
```

Comment: yes, your other answer inspired this.   I tried your solution here and I get `#{}`  I am having trouble seeing where it is failing.

Comment: The root should be a branch like this: `(def test-data2
  [:root 
   [:a 
    [:x 
     [:y 
      [:t [:l2]]] 
     [:z [:l3]]]] 
   [:b 
    [:c 
     [:d [:l4]] 
     [:e [:l5]]]]])`

Comment: As each node is of this structure:  `[node-name & children]`

Comment: One thing though - how do you get this to stop descending the tree once a match has been found?   The non-functional code in my question will stop at `(:root :a :x)` and not return `(:root :a :x :y)`.   It looks like your code searches the entire tree rather than stopping down a certain branch.

Comment: DFS will get you to `(:root :a :x :y, :t)` as the first path meeting the condition.  `(:root :a :x, :z)` is next so you won't be able to retract previous answer.  Looks like you are asking for BFS.

Answer (score 2):

The exception comes from your `children-have-leaves?` function.

The `(not (empty? z/children))` expression fails, because [z/children](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.zip/children) is a function, however, [empty?](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/empty_q) must be invoked on a collection.

What you need is a predicate that returns `true` if a node has children, like: `(fn [x] (not (empty? (z/children x))))` or shorter: `(comp not empty? z/children)`

The correct implementation:

```
(defn children-have-leaves?
  [loc]
  (some->> loc
           (iterate z/children)
           (take-while z/branch?)
           (atleast-one? (comp not empty? z/children))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  that solves my crash.  But I guess there's a problem with my code since it now prints every path and not just desired ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process tree-like data structures, I would highly recommend [the tupelo.forest library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/docs/forest.adoc).

I don't understand your goal, though.  Nodes `:a` and `:c` in your example are not equally distant from the closest leaf.

**Actually, I just noticed** that the tree in your example ***is different*** than the tree in your code attempt.  Could you please update the question to make them consistent?

---

Here is an example of how you could do it:

```
(dotest ; find the grandparent of each leaf
  (hid-count-reset)
  (with-forest (new-forest)
    (let [data              [:root
                             [:a
                              [:x
                               [:y [:t [:l2]]]
                               [:z [:l3]]]]
                             [:b [:c
                                  [:d [:l4]]
                                  [:e [:l5]]]]]
          root-hid          (add-tree-hiccup data)
          leaf-paths        (find-paths-with root-hid [:** :*] leaf-path?)
          grandparent-paths (mapv #(drop-last 2 %) leaf-paths)
          grandparent-tags  (set
                              (forv [path grandparent-paths]
                                (let [path-tags (it-> path
                                                  (mapv #(hid->node %) it)
                                                  (mapv #(grab :tag %) it))]
                                  path-tags)))]
      (is= (format-paths leaf-paths)
        [[{:tag :root} [{:tag :a} [{:tag :x} [{:tag :y} [{:tag :t} [{:tag :l2}]]]]]]
         [{:tag :root} [{:tag :a} [{:tag :x} [{:tag :z} [{:tag :l3}]]]]]
         [{:tag :root} [{:tag :b} [{:tag :c} [{:tag :d} [{:tag :l4}]]]]]
         [{:tag :root} [{:tag :b} [{:tag :c} [{:tag :e} [{:tag :l5}]]]]]])
      (is= grandparent-tags
          #{[:root :a :x] 
            [:root :a :x :y] 
            [:root :b :c]} ))))
```